# Rendering a list in React doesn't populate any elements to the DOM

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of objects which I want to render in the components `return` function.
However, for some reason nothing is rendered at all.

I'm following along this [official React guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component)

```
const DashboardOffers = () => {

    // Get queryset of Offers
    let qs_offers = []
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offer/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            qs_offers = result
            console.log(qs_offers)
        })

    // Create array of objects to render
    const offer_items = qs_offers.map((offer) =>
        <div>{offer.identifier}</div>
    );

    return (
        <div>{offer_items}</div>
    )
}
export default DashboardOffers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it into a hook component,

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

> Hooks are functions that let you “hook into” React state and lifecycle
> features from function components. Hooks don’t work inside classes —
> they let you use React without classes. (We don’t recommend rewriting
> your existing components overnight but you can start using Hooks in
> the new ones if you’d like.)

```
const DashboardOffers = () => {
  const [offers, setOffers] = useState([]);
  // Get queryset of Offers
  useEffect(() => {
    let qs_offers = []; // possibly not needed.
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offer/", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setOffers([...offers, result])
        console.log(qs_offers);
      });
  }, [offers]); // optional

  // Create array of objects to render
  const offer_items = qs_offers.map((offer) => <div>{offer.identifier}</div>);

  return <div>{offer_items}</div>;
};
export default DashboardOffers;
```

Comment: Nice that works! Thanks. One question: Is it a structure to put fetch stuff into useEffect hook?

Comment: Yes, its the most ideal and common way fetch calls get called at.